# Is there an appropriate version of Pygame for Python 3.7 installed with Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, anaconda, spyder

I'm new to programming and I just downloaded Anaconda a few days ago for Windows 64-bit. I came across the Invent with Python book and decided I wanted to work through it so I downloaded that too. I ended up running into a couple issues with it not working (somehow I ended up with Spyder (Python 2.7) and end=' ' wasn't doing what it was supposed to so I uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda -- though originally I did download the 3.7 version). It looked as if I had the 2.7 version of Pygame. I'm looking around and I don't see a Pygame version for Python 3.7 that is compatible with Anaconda. The only ones I saw were for Mac or not meant to work with Anaconda. This is all pretty new to me so I'm not sure what my options are. Thanks in advance.
Also, how do I delete the incorrect Pygame version?

Comment: `pip install pygame`. It does exist for Python 3.7.

Comment: This works with Anaconda?

Comment: What does Pygame imported but unused mean?

Comment: "This works with Anaconda?" - This does. There's nothing mystical about Anaconda, just a bunch of libraries and additional tools bundled with regular Python of whatever version.

Comment: Sorry, I was just going off of what it said about Anaconda here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Thank you.
I tried it with some code in spyder but I got "imported but unused"

Comment: A binary distribution of pygame (or any other library), pre-built against a particular Python distribution, won't work with another, binary-incompatible Python distribution (different major version, win32/amd64, etc.) For what I know, however, Anaconda uses the same (or at least binary compatible) Python as the standard Python. WHL files from that site work with Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

just use `pip install pygame` & **python will look for a version compatible with your installation.**

If you're using Anaconda and `pip` doesn't work on `CMD prompt`, try using the `Anaconda prompt` from start menu.